# Randomising array in angularjs using filter method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, random, filter

I have some filter options for my array like this:

```
$scope.sortableItems = {    'random' : 'Filter Random',
                                'test1' : 'Filter test1',
                                'test2' : 'Filter test2',
                                'test3' : 'Filter test3'
                            };
```

Then I set:

```
$scope.sortKey =  'random';
$scope.reverse = false;
```

And my array is created like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.jsonData.length; i++) {
        var item = { "test1": $scope.jsonData[i].test1, "test2": $scope.jsonData[i].test2, "test3" : $scope.jsonData[i].test3};
        $scope.results.push(item);
}
```

Then I use:

```
$scope.results = $filter('orderBy')($scope.results, $scope.sortKey, $scope.reverse);
```

And I have a method:

```
$scope.random = function(){
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
};
```

And finally I use:

```
ng-repeat="r in results|orderBy:sortKey:reverse"
```

in my html. This does not work!

However, when I set manually:

```
ng-repeat="r in results|orderBy:random"
```

then it works! Why can I not use a variable??

Comment: add the random function to you order filter

Comment: `<p ng-repeat="i in jsonData |orderBy:random">{{i}}</p>`

Comment: I just extended my answer. I already did that! @JesusCarrasco --> r in results|orderBy:sortKey:reverse --> sortKey can become: random, test1, test2, test3. So it should work?

Comment: I have updated my question. You might wanna have another look. @JesusCarrasco